# Auto Completion in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm currently trying VS2010 and while it's smooth, good looking, sexy would I even add, I've met a MAJOR Turn off, being still a big teen noob in C and C++, I need my AUTO Completion until I learn some of the lib's members.

I tried toggling the CTRL+ALT+SPACE Option, using the hotkeys, the Button in the EDIT Tab is disabled (grey) And LASTLY I tried it using the command but got a message saying that it's disabled. It works in other languages.

Comment: Are you using C++/CLI? If so there is no intellisense in VS2010 and it will return in a future version. If you are using native C++, you should have much better intellisense than you had in VS2008.

Comment: I am only testing on a Console (native C/Cpp)

Comment: "i need my AUTO Completition" Sigh. Kids these days. I miss my first programmable micro-calculator, and my second "toy" computer - programming by inputting pure hex/octal numbers was very entertaining, and implementing division/multiplication by hand was a very good brain exercise. Modern newbies don't have to deal with something like that, and learn less as a result. Which is sad.

Comment: True and but at least i'm trying to go "down the language ladder" since i actually started 2 years ago with C#. Now i'm learning C & Unmanaged Cpp and perhaps someday i'l even touch a bit of M ASM.
Thanks to the summer vacation, we can go fast at this ;).
thx for the advice.

Comment: You're sure your project is a 'Win32 project' or 'Win32 Console Application' and not 'CLR Console App'?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/raulperez/visual-c-intellisense-options-on-visual-studio-2010)) explains how to disable it ... perhaps you can use it to reverse the process? If you would like to see how nice VS2010 intellisense for C++ is compared to 2008, take a look at http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/DEV316

Comment: I've made sure using the first page you've linked me to that all options were set to what they should be but it still doesn't work.
and it really looks good tho ;(